# Iterate through a XML file using Depth-first seach method using XPATH (or anything else) in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am trying to iterate thought all the menu of an application automatically. This is a part of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ke3600-menu-file language="en" display="English" index="1">
  <version major="0" minor="1" patch="0"/>
  <locale name="en_EN" timezone="CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3"/>
  <menu name="main_menu" display="Main Menu">
    <menu name="broadband" display="Broadband" help="100_help_broadband">
      <onenter proc="activateGfast"/>
      <menu name="load_save_profiles" display="Load and Save Profiles" help="601_help_profiles">
        <application name="load_profiles" display="Load Profile"/>
        <application name="save_profiles" display="Save Profile"/>
        <application name="remove_profiles" display="Delete Profile"/>
      </menu>
      <parameter type="list" name="wanInterface" display="Interface" help="101_help_wanInterface">
        <value id="0" name="ifDSL" display="xDSL"/>
        <value id="1" name="ifSFP" display="SFP"/>
        <value id="2" name="ifETH" display="Ethernet"/>
        <!-- <value i d="3" name="ifWLAN" display="WLAN"/> -->
        <value id="4" name="ifSHDSL" display="SHDSL"/>
      </parameter>

      <menu name="xdslinterface" display="xDSL Interface" help="200_help_xDslInterface">
        <parameter type="list" name="annex" display="xDSL Mode" help="201_help_xdslModi">
          <value id="0" name="xdsl_line_annex_a" display="Annex A/M"/>
          <value id="1" name="xdsl_line_annex_b" display="Annex B/J"/>
        </parameter>
        <application name="xdsl_macAddr" display="MAC Address" caption="MAC Address">
          <param type="string" name="xdsl_mac_addr" display="MAC Address" length="25"/>
        </application>
        <parameter type="list" name="xdsl_vectoring_mode" display="Vectoring Mode" help="202_help_Vectoring">
          <value id="0" name="xdsl_vectoring_mode_disabled" display="Disabled"/>
          <value id="1" name="xdsl_vectoring_mode_enabled" display="Enabled"/>
          <value id="2" name="xdsl_vectoring_mode_friendly" display="Friendly"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="xdsl_gfast_mode" display="G.FAST">
          <value id="0" name="xdsl_gfast_mode_disabled" display="Disabled"/>
          <value id="1" name="xdsl_gfast_mode_enabled" display="Enabled"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="resync" display="Auto Re-Sync">
          <value id="1" name="re_sync_on" display="On"/>
          <value id="0" name="re_sync_off" display="Off"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="seamlessRateAdaption" display="Seamless Rate Adaption">
          <value id="0" name="sra_off" display="Off"/>
          <value id="1" name="sra_on" display="On"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="xdsl_ginp" display="G.INP">
          <value id="0" name="xdsl_ginp_none" display="Off"/>
          <value id="1" name="xdsl_ginp_down" display="Down"/>
          <value id="2" name="xdsl_ginp_up" display="Up"/>
          <value id="3" name="xdsl_ginp_both" display="Down/Up"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="power_cut_back" display="Power Cut Back">
          <value id="0" name="power_cut_back_off" display="Off"/>
          <value id="1" name="power_cut_back_on" display="On"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="atmType" display="ATM Type">
          <value id="0" name="atm_type_aal5" display="AAL5"/>
          <value id="1" name="atm_type_aal0pkt" display="AAL0PKT"/>
          <value id="2" name="atm_type_aal0cell" display="AAL0CELL"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="voip_atmType" display="Voip Interface ATM Type">
          <value id="0" name="voip_atm_type_aal5" display="AAL5"/>
          <value id="1" name="voip_atm_type_aal0pkt" display="AAL0PKT"/>
          <value id="2" name="voip_atm_type_aal0cell" display="AAL0CELL"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="iptv_atmType" display="Iptv Interface ATM Type">
          <value id="0" name="iptv_atm_type_aal5" display="AAL5"/>
          <value id="1" name="iptv_atm_type_aal0pkt" display="AAL0PKT"/>
          <value id="2" name="iptv_atm_type_aal0cell" display="AAL0CELL"/>
        </parameter>
      </menu>

      <menu name="ethernetinterface" display="Ethernet Interface" help="300_help_ethernetInterface">
        <parameter type="list" name="ethInterfaceAuto" display="Autonegotiation">
          <value id="1" name="ethInterfaceAutoOn" display="On"/>
          <value id="0" name="ethInterfaceAutoOff" display="Off"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="ethInterfaceSpeed" display="Speed">
          <value id="2" name="ethIf1000" display="1000MBit/s"/>
          <value id="1" name="ethIf100" display="100MBit/s"/>
          <value id="0" name="ethIf10" display="10MBit/s"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter type="list" name="ethInterfaceDuplexMode" display="Duplex Mode">
          <value id="1" name="ethIfFull" display="Full"/>
          <value id="0" name="ethIfHalf" display="Half"/>
        </parameter>
      </menu>
```

I want to make a loop that will go through all the menu using a depth first search (traversing tree starting at the root and explore as far as possible along each branch before backtracking) method. So far I can get the value of a specific node, but I can't figure out how can I automatically go through all the `menu`, `submenu`, `application`, `parameter`, `value` and print their `display` value. Here is the code I have to get the `display` value of a specific branch.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main():
    tree = ET.parse("/home/mr/Desktop/git/KE3600_APP/menu.xml")
    result = ''
    root = tree.getroot()

    for e in tree.findall('.//'):
        test.log(str(root.attrib.get('display')))
```

I have looked into various tutorials, but all of them just goes to a specific node and extract the value, none of them goes through all of them. Please suggest me any tutorial or any sample solution that will help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate from root:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file = "menus.xml"

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

def process_menu(menu):
    print('Processing: {}'.format(menu.get('display')))
    for item in menu.getchildren():
        if (item.tag != "menu"):
            print(item)
        else:
            process_menu(item)

for menu in root.iter("menu"):
    process_menu(menu)
```

Comment: This gives me the name of all the menus. How should I include all the `application`, `parameter` and `value` inside it? That's what I meant by all the submenus. Sorry my question wasn't clearly explained.

Comment: I updated the answer, now you have access to parameter and application nodes in the line print(item). Hope it helps.

Comment: This works perfectly. It shows everything except the `value id`. Can you please have a look again? Thanks a lot.